# "Why couldn't" vs. "why couldn't you have"

Tags: past-tense, auxiliary-verbs

Reading Harry Potter 2, I came across the following, and I wonder if the use of *couldn't have* is the equivalent of *couldn't* in this context?

> "I have got a question, Oliver," said George, who had woken with a start. "Why **couldn't you have** told us all this yesterday when we were all awake?"

If we change it to the following, how does it change the meaning of it?

> "I have got a question, Oliver," said George, who had woken with a start. "Why **couldn't you** tell us all this yesterday when we were all awake?"

And what is the difference between the following?

> If you **couldn't** do it, you should have told us yesterday.
>
> If you **couldn't have** done it, you should have told us yesterday.

Comment: When I was learning English back in the day, my teacher told me that we use 'couldn't have done' (Present Perfect) when the action we're talking about has implications on the present.

Answer (score 5):

*Could* is sometimes called the "remote" form of *can*. Sometimes it acts like a simple past tense:

> Yesterday I **couldn't** see the problem, but today I **can**.
>   ≅ Yesterday I **wasn't able to** see the problem, but today I **am**.

but sometimes it acts like a conditional:

> I **couldn't** do it if I tried.
>   ≅ I **wouldn't be able to** do it if I tried.

or emphasizes the vagueness of a possibility:

> Anything **could** happen between now and November.
>   ≅ Anything **can** happen, **maybe**, between now and November.

and sometimes it's simply more polite:

> **Could** you pass the salt?
>   ≅ **Can** you pass the salt, **please**?

In your example, both Rowling's "couldn't you have told" and your "couldn't you tell" would be correct. In your "couldn't you tell", *could* is acting as a past tense. In Rowling's "couldn't you have told", it's *have* that's providing the past-tense sense, and *could* is serving a less well-defined role. It could be interpreted as a conditional:

> Why **couldn't** you **have told** us all this yesterday when we were all awake?
>   ≅ Why **wouldn't** you **have been able to tell** us all this yesterday when we were all awake?
>   ≅ You decided not to tell us all this yesterday when we were awake. Why? What made you think you **wouldn't be able to**?

. . . but for language-learning purposes, I think it might be better to think of *could have* as an idiom, and not try to unpack it too much. To ask why something "couldn't have" happened is to invoke the idea of alternate world where it did, and *could*'s vague conditional sense is perfect for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the difference is really in "why couldn't you **have told**" as opposed to "why couldn't you **tell**". The tense difference is subtle, but the present form "tell" implies that the failing is something he could or should remedy now. Of course this is impossible, but there is a greater sense of current failing.

The past version - "have told" implies that his failing is that when it was yesterday, he didn't tell them. The failing is in not having done something in the past, without the sense that there is a failing in the present.

The past tense is better, because it puts all of the action in the past, where is belongs. The present tens is actually mixing up the times. However it works when there is a desire to imply that they should do something now to make up for it.

The response to "have told" might be "because I didn't realise it was important until now" - the past failing is only seen in the current light. The response to "tell" might be "I hate you and i want you all to die" - there is an ongoing sense of guilt.